# 0.999... = 1? What is the secret?

Tags: arithmetic

If **x = 0.999... (a)** -> 10x=9.999... -> 10x-x=(9.999...)-(0.999...) 
-> 9x = 9 -> **x = 9/9 = 1 (b)**

x = 0.999 (a) = 1 (b) ?

So... what is the right explanation for this occur? I know that exists a tiny error somewhere... I think that the subtraction of the repeating decimal is incorrect, because the principle of infinity. That's it?
Am I right?

Comment: Why do you think, that $0.\overline{9}\ne 1$?

Comment: what does $0.9999\ldots$ mean exactly ?

Comment: There is no error.  Although you have to be careful with addition of infinite series it is handled properly here.

Comment: If 0.999... = 1, why there is a need to sum 0.999... + 0.001... to match 1?

Comment: @Marco it doesn't

Comment: I have edited my comment.

Comment: @GrahamKemp well not sure Macro gets that, so you have to explain **him** not me

Comment: @Marco it is still wrong. Just do the addition by hand. What happens after the first $1$?

Comment: The easiest explanation I've seen for this is as follows: $\frac{1}{3}=.333...$.$\frac{1}{3}\times3=1=.999...$

Comment: @GrahamKemp I think you mean $9/10^k$ as it's incorrect the way you wrote it.

Comment: @AaronM that really proves the question?

Comment: @Marco If you want to keep the nice properties of algebra that we have (without working from surreals), it must be that $.999... = 1$.

Comment: I would like to point out that $0.000...1$ makes no sense as a number.  For a decimal expansion of a given number, if there is a $1$, it must occur *somewhere* (and "at the infinityth place" is not somewhere).

Comment: Let $x=0.000...1$ then $\lim_{x \to0^+} 1-x=1$

Comment: OP probably does not know what limits are.

Comment: @D_S $0.000...1 = 0.000...0999...$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll recommend you the best article I know in this subject. [**Fred Richman's:** *Is $0.999\dots=1$?*](https://studentportalen.uu.se/uusp-filearea-tool/download.action?nodeId=754744&toolAttachmentId=145726) [MAA: Mathematics Magazine, $12/1999$].

From the beginning: *"Arguing whether $0.999\dots=1$ is a popular sport on the newsgroup sci.math. It seems that people are often too quick to dismiss the idea that these numbers might be different."*

The article is interesting because it actually discusses why it is and why it couldn't be. What are the needed tools for it to be. Also, there are amazing references.

**EDIT:** I also recommend Courant's Differential and Integral Calculus
 [(Chapter 1, Section2)](https://archive.org/stream/DifferentialIntegralCalculusVolI/Courant-DifferentialIntegralCalculusVolI#page/n23/mode/2up). There is a great explanation in there which makes the subject appear less magic that it seems.

Answer (score 2):

There is no error in your logic. Infinity does weird things, and one thing it does is that the infinitely long decimal expression $0.999...$ turns out to be equal to 1. The implication is that there are actually many real numbers with two equivalent decimal expressions for them (so $0.5829999... = 0.583$, for example).

There's a [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...) that goes into ridiculously deep detail on the matter.

Comment: 10*(10/10.001...)-(10/10.001...)=
10*x-x=9x
9x = (10/10.001...)/9=
x = [(10/10.001...)/9]/9
x = 0,0123443074226321

I messed up on something?

Comment: That is to explain that 9x (x=(10/10.001...) is equal to 0.999..., so x is different than 1.

Comment: Where is that .001 coming from?  It does not exist.

Comment: I mean 10,001... is equal to 10,000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001

Comment: @Marco then you mean 10,000...01, whatever that means

Comment: Yes, thanks @Omnomnomnom

Comment: @Marco or do you mean 10,000...001?  Are those different?  And what would you make of 10,000...00999...?

Comment: I think 10,000...01 is the same that 10,000...001, but i did not know why did you ask that.

Comment: In the real numbers, there's no such thing as the last decimal place, so there's nowhere to put that 1 you're trying to put. The limit of the sequence (1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, ...) is exactly 0.

Answer (score 2):

A priori, real numbers have nothing to do with decimals.  If you want to see why this is, look up Peano arithmetic and the precise definition of real numbers.

It just so happens that every real number can be written out in decimal form.  However, the decimal expansion of a given real number need not be unique.  The real numbers corresponding to the decimal forms

$$1.0000 \cdots$$

$$0.9999 \cdots$$

are the same, as you have observed.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align} x ~=~& 0.\dot{\overline 9}\\[1ex] ~=~& \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \tfrac 9{10^k} \\[2ex] 10 x ~=~& \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \tfrac {9}{10^{k-1}}\\[1ex] ~=~& 9+ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=2}^n \tfrac {9}{10^{k-1}}\\[1ex] ~=~& 9+ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \tfrac {9}{10^{j}} \tag{$\star$} \\[1ex] ~=~& 9+ x\\[2ex]  9x~=~&9 \\[1ex] x~=~&1
\end{align}$$

---

$(\star)$: Assuming the limit of $F(n)$ as $n\to\infty$ exists, then $F(n-1)$ has the same limit.